# simple JSON array to Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I would like to take the following JSON and convert it to an array

```
declare @com nvarchar(MAX)

set @com = '{"IDs":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,83,84,88,89,90,91,97,98,99,100,101,102,104,108,109,110,111,112,114,115,116,118,119,121,122,123,124,125,126,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,152,153,154]}';

select isJson(@com)

select * from openjson(@com)
    with (commodities varchar(50) 'strict $.IDs')
```

But when I do I get the following error what am I doing wrong ?

```
Object or array cannot be found in the specified JSON path.
```

Comment: Your syntax `with (commodities varchar(50) 'strict $.IDs')` requires the array index be supplied such as `with (commodities varchar(50) 'strict $.IDs[0]')`.  However, -Shnugo has answered correctly for this I believe in order to extract all values in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've put the path in the wrong place. Try this

```
select * from openjson(@com,'strict $.IDs')
```

The returned set includes the element's position (in `key`) and its value and type.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking to join to fields that are in a JSON array in MySQL, here is a query that uses FIND_IN_SET to join an array of IDs to another table.

It does not perform well but it works.

(MySQL 5.7 does not support REGEXP_REPLACE)

```
select c.classId, c.className, replace(replace(replace(replace(sc.classes->>'$.classIds','"',''),'[',''),']',''),' ','')
from studentClasses sc
join classes c on find_in_set(c.classId,replace(replace(replace(replace(sc.classes->>'$.classIds','"',''),'[',''),']',''),' ',''))
where 1
limit 10;
```

The classes JSON column looks like this:

```
    "classIds": [
        "d4ae08d0-c27c-11ea-87f0-3508520d9867",
        "556c3060-d0f5-11ea-995d-9709c7e03f55",
        "558eac80-d0f5-11ea-995d-9709c7e03f55",
        "559192b0-d0f5-11ea-995d-9709c7e03f55",
        "d57613c0-c27c-11ea-87f0-3508520d9867",
        "d551e9f0-c27c-11ea-87f0-3508520d9867",
        "d4b44a60-c27c-11ea-87f0-3508520d9867"
    ]
}
```